# Fantasy novel set in an alternative Roman era about a blacksmith's daughter who is sold to a slave trader by her mother

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story is about a blacksmith's 18 year old daughter that has been trained to make swords and has secretly been training to fight. She is with her 2 brothers and a friend watching a fighting tournament when her younger brother falls into the arena. She jumps in and fights off a wild cat, some how with her mind after losing her sword, and saves him. She is hired by a member of royal ruling class as a weapons handler, but before she can start is sold to a slave trader by her mother, who hates and mistreats her. That’s as far as I got. I think her name was Cara.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: I started to read it a week ago as a free kindle book but lost it when kindle did a reset for my account password. I have no idea when it was published and a search on kindle is hopeless.

Comment: What about it was science-fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @Jenayah Alternative history is on-topic, I think?

Comment: @Rand the question depicts mundane (albeit unusual) stuff that could very well have happened in the Roman era we know of. The title mentions an "alternative history" but so far the post's content does not hint towards anything more than a historical fiction set in the plain old Roman empire.

Comment: What makes it alternative history?

Comment: The ruler was King Claudius and the fighters were not called gladiators, it was something like fightlords or warlords. The main character did something magical to kill the giant cat when she saved her brother. And the arena although not called the Colosseum was in partial ruins.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're talking about the [Of Crowns and Glory](http://www.morganricebooks.com/book/slave-warrior-queen/) series by Morgan Rice. This is the Amazon description:

> 17 year old **Ceres**, a beautiful, poor girl in the Empire city of
> Delos, lives the harsh and unforgiving life of a commoner. **By day
> she delivers her father's forged weapons to the palace training
> grounds, and by night she secretly trains with them**, yearning to be
> a warrior in a land where girls are forbidden to fight. With her
> **pending sale to slavehood**, she is desperate.

The name is close and it's the only thing I've found so far that's got sword forging, slavery, magic, a female protagonist, and an empire.